# "Cater to" vs. "cater for"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between "cater to" and "cater for"? Which is better in this context:

1. The dramatist must cater to the taste of the audience.
2. The dramatist must cater for the taste of the audience.

I found another discussion on similar lines but it was between "cater to" and "cater towards". Seems both "to" and "for" are correct. But I wish to know if there are specific contexts in which one is picked over the other.

I did search for this in a few online dictionaries, and also I found this exact question on WordReference.com, but the answers were divided. Many seemed to think they are the same. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cater?s=t) gives clearly separate examples for both but has added in brackets that both to and for can be used to mean 'pander to'. Hence the confusion.

> 1. to provide food, service, etc., as for a party or wedding:
>      *to cater for a banquet.*
> 2. to provide or supply what amuses, is desired, or gives pleasure, comfort, etc. (usually followed by *to* or *for*):
>      *to cater to popular demand; to cater to an invalid.*
>
> [...] 
>   
> (**intransitive; foll by for or to**) to provide what is required or desired (for): *to cater for a need, cater to your tastes*

There is quite a lot of stuff on this topic, but it's mostly ambiguous.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71797/discussion-on-question-by-shef-cater-to-vs-cater-for).

Answer (score 1):

I want to believe "cater to" is American, while "cater for" is British. Much the same way as "different than" is American, while "different from" is British.

Comment: Can you offer any links or sources to support this usage as something standard, or is it just your personal usage?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference of both preps lies in actual meaning not in accent or context.

Cater *for* is used to say that you provide a perticular group of people with what is needed or wanted by them.

Cater *to* usually expresses the idea that you'll provide what exactly a particular group of people want especially sth that is unusual or that people think is wrong or messed up.

Examples:

She wants to cater for her blind employees by providing the company's facilities with notices that include the texts in Braille.

I used to freak out when I saw on TV the politician had finally agreed to cater for the French government just for his own economic interest.

(sorry for the hectic sentences I wrote)

Comment: “*I **used to freak out** when I saw on TV the politician had finally agreed* …” It seems highly unlikely that  this was a recurring incident. A better alternative would be to say ”**I freaked out** *when I saw on TV the politician had finally agreed* …”